# Why can't I move my unmanned rocket?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have an unmanned rocket in Kerbal Space Program.  I have batteries and solar panels and I am clearly not out of electricity.  I still can't control my rocket at all though.

Why can't I control the rocket?

Answer (score 5):

Unlike the manned command modules, the first unmanned command module (Stayputnik Mk. 1) does not include any sort of reaction wheels in it.  In order to gain control of the rocket you will need to add an Inline Reaction Wheel to your vessel.

Comment: Another option is turning on the engine if it has gimbaling. It's much better to have an inline reaction wheel like you said (but that requires forethought), in case he wants to save the current probe, engine gimbaling might help.